# Problem with Hibernate/JPA Query and categories

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hql, categories

I have a Hibernate/JPA data model that lets me place objects (MyObj) into various categories (MyCategory).  Each category may have 0 or more subcategories, and categories that do not instead have a classification (MyClassification) assigned to them.  The data model looks something like this:

```
public class MyObj {

    …

    protected MyCategory category = null;

    …
}

public class MyCategory {

    …

    protected MyClassification classification=null;

    protected List<MyCategory> childCategories=null;

    protected MyCategory parentCategory=null;

    …

}

public class MyClassification {

    …

}
```

I'd like to be able to query for MyObj instances based on classification, category, or subcategory.  For example, if I have 3 classifications (classA, classB, and classC), and 6 categories (e.g. categoryA1, categoryA2, categoryB1, etc. where the name corresponds to the classification) and each of those categories have 3 subcategories (e.g. subcatA1, subcatA2, subcatA3, subcatB1, etc.) I'd like to do queries like this:

- All MyObj instances in classification classA (regardless of category or subcategory)
- All MyObj instances in category categoryA1 (regardless of subcategory)

I've created a couple of NamedQueries that I thought would accomplish this.  They work fine for instances where a MyObj instance has been assigned to a subcategory.  However, if I place a MyObj instance in a category (no subcategory) and query based on class, I don't see it.  I only see MyObj instances that are inside of a subcategory.  My queries look like this:

```
MyObj.findByClass = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObj o WHERE (o.category.classification = :classification OR o.category.parentCategory.classification = :classification)"

MyObj.findByCategory = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObj o WHERE (o.category = :category OR o.category.parentCategory = :category)"
```

Can anyone tell me where the error is in my logic for these queries?  Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your query is that `o.category.parentCategory` is written like `inner join category cat on cat.id=o.parent_category`, and if a `parentCategory` is `NULL` you won't get any result.

So dot-navigation implies inner joins which causes problems with `OR` statements. You must use explicit `LEFT JOINs` or `UNION` queries.

On a sidenote, QueryDSL allows to write statements like this:

```
from(QCategory.category)
.where(QCategory.category.classification.eq(classification).or(QCategory.category.left().parentCategory().left().classification.eq(classification))
.listDisticnt(QCategory.category)
```

SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObj o WHERE (o.category.classification = :classification OR o.category.parentCategory.classification = :classification)"

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing a "classification" in the first query, after the OR:

```
MyObj.findByClass = "SELECT DISTINCT o FROM MyObj o WHERE (o.category.classification = :classification OR o.category.parentCategory.classification = :classification)"
```

On a side note, my feeling is that traversing the object graph is more straightforward than issuing HQL queries

Comment: Corrected the missing field in the query.

Comment: is right, SQL (or HQL) is not able to search in trees in a simple way... You could search all categories with classification you want and the use a second HQL to search all Obj with any of the categories you found.